# Redirect http default port to an application on same port - CentOS 7

Tags: apache, centos7

I have an installation of httpd on my server and a web application on it (`/var/www/html/app`). I want to when a user enter the IP of my server over HTTP (`123.125.21.45:80`) this redirects to my application on same port (`123.125.21.45:80/app`)

I have created and app.conf in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/app.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/html/app
  ServerName 123.125.21.45
</VirtualHost>
```

And the result on the web browser is

```
http://123.125.21.45/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/app/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below virtual host file and then try.

Note: make sure you are not using any redirection from `.htaccess` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName 123.125.21.45
    Redirect permanent / http://123.125.21.45/app/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```